# C# how to compare range two numbers difference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having trouble comparing range two numbers in C# MVC model loop. The inside loop example SequenceId(int) numbers 1,2,4,6,7,9,12,16 etc...  What I need to find Rage = next Number - previous Number.

This is my C# method.

```cs
if (model != null && ModelState.IsValid)
{
    foreach (var list in model)
    {
        int sIdRage = 1;
        int Interval =15;
        int previousNumber =1;
        //SequenceId will be 1,2,4,6,7,9,12,16 etc...
        // First Loop sIdRage = 1
        int sId = list.SequenceId;
        int nextNumber = (sId - previousNumber);
        //For the third loop nextNumber = 4 and previousNumbe = 2
        // sIdRage = nextNumber - previousNumbe
        // sIdRage = 2
        sIdRage += (sId - previousNumber);           
        count += TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Interval * sIdRage);
        list.FromTime = count.ToString();
        db.Entry(list).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Declare previous number outside the loop

Comment: Can you include a simpler/minimal code example of what you are trying? From the list of integers `1,2,4,6,7,9,12,16` do you want to calculate and get another list something like `1,2,2,1,2,3,4,16` ?

Comment: Number will come always ascending order, some time 1,2,2,3,3,5,7,8,9,11,14 etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect. You are continuously initializing your variables within the loop therefore it wont work. Also see my comment in the code close to the bottom. It should be like this

```
if (model != null && ModelState.IsValid)
{
    int sIdRage = 1;
    int Interval =15;
    int previousNumber =1;
    //SequenceId will be 1,2,4,6,7,9,12,16 etc...
    // First Loop sIdRage = 1

    foreach (var list in model)
    {
        int sId = list.SequenceId;
        int nextNumber = (sId - previousNumber);
        //For the third loop nextNumber = 4 and previousNumbe = 2
        // sIdRage = nextNumber - previousNumbe
        // sIdRage = 2
        sIdRage += (sId - previousNumber);           
        count += TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Interval * sIdRage);
        list.FromTime = count.ToString();
        previousNumber = sId; //this line of code has been added for keeping track of previous number , otherwise it will always use previousNumber = 1
        //Note... you need to add a faile to which you are saving the list
        //EG db.Customers.Entry(list) where Customers would be the table
        //in which you would save

        db.Entry(list).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: You code previousNumber always 1. For example 3,5 previousNumber is 3